# Writing dict of lists to csv, specifing column order

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

i am doing the following:

```
import csv 
d={'a':(1,2,3), '2':(4,5,6), '3':(7,8,9)}

csv_file = open('test.csv','w')
writefile = csv.writer(csv_file)
writefile.writerow(d.keys())

with open('test.csv', "wb") as outfile:
   writer = csv.writer(outfile)
   writer.writerow(d.keys())
   writer.writerows(zip(*d.values()))
```

this leads to a .csv file i can process with further tools.
Unfortunately a dict does not contain any order concerning the keys. One of theses lists inside the dict contains time values. I would prefer to have this list at first in the csv. About the order of the other columns i dont care.
But i have no idea how i can realise this functionality.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `collections` package contains an `OrderedDict` class that guarantees the order of the keys and values will be the same when you access them as when you created them. So you could do something like this:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
d = OrderedDict([('a', (1,2,3)), ('2', (4,5,6)), ('3', (7,8,9))])
...rest of your code...
```

Note that the `OrderedDict` is constructed using a list of tuples rather than a dictionary. This is because we need to guarantee that the order we write the keys and values in is preserved.

Comment: Thank you so much, your solution worked. It was exectly what i was looking for :)

Answer (score 2):

You can create ordered dictionaries if you need to remember the order of your key - value pairs.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#ordereddict-objects

Answer (score 0):

The Python `dict` keys are sorted by its hash. If you want further info on this you can check this awesome video from PyCon 2010: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C4Kc8xzcA68

---

You can sort the keys into a list, and then access the values with that list:

```
sorted_keys = sorted(d.keys()) # use this instead of d.keys()
sorted_values = (d[k] for k in sorted_keys) # use this instead of d.values()
```